# How to build a CMake project with subproject(s)?

Tags: c++, cmake

I have the following file structure:

```
-- root/
  -- CMakeLists.txt
  -- headers/
  -- src/
  -- external/
    -- tui/
      -- CmakeLists.txt
      -- headers/
      -- src/
```

The problem is that the linker fails with `undefined reference to` errors related to the method calls which are defined in the *external/tui/* directory.

CMakeLists.txt in the root/ dir:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.27)

project(a.out VERSION 0.1 LANGUAGES CXX)

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 20)
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD_REQUIRED ON)
add_compile_options(-g)

file(GLOB HEADER_FILES headers/*.h)
file(GLOB SOURCE_FILES src/*.cpp)
add_subdirectory(external/tui)
add_executable(a.out ${HEADER_FILES} ${SOURCE_FILES})

target_link_libraries(a.out PRIVATE tui)
```

CMakeLists.txt in the _external/tui/ dir:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.27)

project(tui)

find_package(Curses REQUIRED)

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 20)
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD_REQUIRED ON)
add_compile_options(-g)

file(GLOB HEADER_FILES headers/*.h)
file(GLOB SOURCE_FILES src/*.cpp)
add_library(tui STATIC ${HEADER_FILES} ${SOURCE_FILES})

target_link_libraries(tui PRIVATE -lncurses)
```

Comment: "related to the method calls which are defined in the external/tui/ directory" - It seems that those methods are NOT actually defined in the source files, from which `tui` library is built. Please, add **exact error message** to the question post. Also add the **C++ code** which defines the method in the source file.

Comment: Note that using glob in cmake is not recommended as it won't notice if new files are added

Answer (score 0):

You are probably missing `target_include_directories(${PROJECT_NAME} PUBLIC ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/headers)` in your library.

Example CMakeLists for static libraries:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.13)
project(example)
add_library(${PROJECT_NAME} "")

target_compile_options(
    ${PROJECT_NAME} PRIVATE ${FLAGS} $<$<COMPILE_LANGUAGE:CXX>:${CPP_FLAGS}> $<$<CONFIG:Debug>:${DEBUG_FLAGS}>
                            $<$<CONFIG:Release>:${RELEASE_FLAGS}>
)

target_sources(${PROJECT_NAME} PRIVATE list.cpp your.cpp sources.cpp
    no.cpp need.cpp for.cpp headers.cpp here.cpp
)

# list dirs that should be looked for header files. Public will be appended to
# other targets that will depend on this one.
target_include_directories(${PROJECT_NAME} PUBLIC ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR})

target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME} PRIVATE ${REQ_LIBS})
```